# Menu fica em cima quando vejo snippet em tela cheia!

Tags: bug

Nesta nova versão do StackOverflow, quando clico para Executar um código e clico para ver na "Tela Toda", o menu apresenta um Z-Index maior do que da div do código e consequentemente fica em cima de tudo, as vezes impossibilitando que se veja qualquer coisa. Vide a seguinte foto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]